# How to unlock a locked (not 'closed' but 'locked') question?

Tags: support

My question [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13515/where-can-i-find-the-training-logs-of-as-many-as-possible-athletes?noredirect=1#comment23694_13515) has been locked

> due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated. For extended
>   discussions, please use chat.

Does it mean that it will not be able to receive any answer?

Will it be 'unlocked' if I erase comments or do something specific with them? What and how? Can they be moved to a chat now?

In StackExchange sites, am used to move to chat when I see that the "conversation" in the comments is going to be long. But, when it is likely to end in one or two comments, I usually don't pay much attention to the "please consider moving to a chat", considering it is merely a suggestion. But this time the "conversation" lasted more than expected, and also some new users entered it, so that eventually we generated a bunch of comments.

Answer (score 2):

I locked it because all I see is conversation even after reading all the comments. If you want to discuss this topic further, which is perfectly fine, then please take them to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/324/the-locker-room). [Comments](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) should be used for clarification of addition of minor information to questions. They should not be for extended discussion.

Your [edit](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/revisions/13515/3) also does not make your question better for this site. Asking for varying opinions on what is useful (which you haven't defined) is the type of question that [should not be asked](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on this site and will result in closure.

> **VERY IMPORTANT EDIT**: I hereby explicitely ask for more than a mere
>   pointer to the data. I would very much welcome additional comments and
>   personal impressions and opinions about the data too. Specially
>   comments that would render the answer useful to casual readers and
>   appropiate to this site purpose.

Personally, your question would be better on [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/). The question can be migrated, but it still needs a lot of cleanup. You are asking a lot of different questions, and I suggest that you make it more focused and specific.

If you want the question reopened (and migrated), please clean the question up first, and notify one of the moderators. We can unlock the question and clean up the comments. Take some time to think about it more thoroughly and construct a concise and clear question.

Comment: How could I "clean the question up first", when I cannot edit it? Do you mean writing it again and posting it again with the same title? Surely not.

Comment: @Mephisto I'll unlock it.

Comment: I simplified the question a lot. I guess it can be migrated now, if you want.